# Xaml, Xamarin.Forms: Make image fit grid container in width and center it

Tags: android, ios, xaml, xamarin.forms

so I worked out my apps layout with the help of a grid and boxviews with colors.

Now i wanna put a button in the yellow box at the bottom.
This button is supposed to fill out the yellow box in width completley and adjust its height accordingly to NOT destroy its aspect ratio. Simple, right? This is the result:

[image]

So, the button sits at the riight place but completely overflows into the next column.
Also, when I render that App on Android, the button is way to small.
(This preview is from Android Emulator, but looks the same on iOS emulator)

This is my code:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Column="0"></BoxView>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Column="1"></BoxView>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Column="2"></BoxView>

        <StackLayout
             Orientation="Horizontal" 
             Grid.Column="1"
             HorizontalOptions="Center"
             VerticalOptions="Center">

            <ImageButton
            Aspect="AspectFill"
            x:Name="btn_mymatches_mainmenu"
            Source="btn_emptydummy.png"/>
        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using grids inside of grids. Makes it looks perfectly if you use percentages :)

```
<!--MainGrid-->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0.6*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="4*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Green" Grid.Row="0"></BoxView>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="1"></BoxView>
        <BoxView BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="2"></BoxView>



        <!--Grid for Button-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ImageButton
                     Aspect="AspectFit"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     x:Name="btn_mymatches_mainmenu"
                     Source="btn_emptydummy.png" BackgroundColor="#00000000"/>
            <Label
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    FontFamily="arial"
                    TextColor="#272727"
                    Text="Meine Matches" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        </Grid>


        <!--Top Level Grid for Notifybutton-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="3">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="0.5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4.5*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Image
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Source="img_notify.png" />
            <Label
                    x:Name="label_notify_nr"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    FontSize="16"
                    FontFamily="arial"
                    TextColor="#ffff"
                    Text="1" 
                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                    VerticalOptions="Center"/>

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
```

REsult:

[image]